# How to filter by tag in Jaeger

Tags: jaeger

When trying to filter by tag, there is a small popup:
[image: jaeger tag filter popup]

I have been looking for `logfmt` around, but all I can find is `key=value` format.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way for something more sophisticated? (starts_with, not equal, contains, etc)
2. I am trying to filter by url using `http.url="http://example.com?bla=bla&foo=bar"`. I am pretty sure the value exists because I am copy/pasting from my trace. I am getting no results. Do I need to escape characters or do something else for this to work?

Comment: Any luck on this? I was mainly interested in the negation part.

Comment: Nope...afaik jaeger is severely lacking in the filter department

Answer (score 1):

I did some research around `logfmt` as well. Based on the [documentation of the original implementation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/kr/logfmt) and in the [Python implementation](https://github.com/jkakar/logfmt-python/blob/master/logfmt/parser.py) of the parser (and [respective tests](https://github.com/jkakar/logfmt-python/blob/master/tests/test_parser.py)), I would say that it doesn't support anything more sophisticated (like starts_with, not equal, contains). And this is because the output of the parser is a simple dictionary (with no regex involved in the values).

As for the second question, using the same mentioned Python parser, I was able to double-check that your filter looks fine:

```
from logfmt import parse_line

parse_line('http.url="http://example.com?bla=bla&foo=bar"')
```

Output:

```
{'http.url': 'http://example.com?bla=bla&foo=bar'}
```

This makes me suspect of an issue on the Jaeger side, but this is as far as I could go.